# Trying to generate random x,y coordinates within a ring in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, math

I am trying to generate random x and y coordinates within a ring, which has an outer radius of 3.5 and an inner radius of 2. Therefor the following must be true for x and y:

```
x**2 + y**2 < 12.25 and x**2 + y**2 > 4
```

I wrote the following function:

```
def meteorites():
    circle = False
    while circle == False:        
        r = np.array([uniform(-6., 6.), uniform(-6., 6.)])
        # we will regenerate random numbers untill the coordinates
        # are within the ring x^2+y^2 < 3,5^2 and x^2+y^2 > 2^2
        if (r[0]**2+r[1]**2 < 12.25) and (r[0]**2+r[1]**2 > 4.):
            circle = True

       else :
            circle = False

    return r[0], r[1]

x = np.zeros(1000)
y = np.zeros(1000)
for i in range(1000):
    x[i] = meteorites()[0]
    y[i] = meteorites()[1]
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

When I plot the resulting coordinates I get a square from -3.5 to 3.5. I can't seem to find the problem. I'm also not sure if it's a coding error, or some dum math problem. Since you guys are usually good at both, can you see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Why not produce a random angle and distance instead, then convert that to an x, y pair?

Comment: @MartijnPieters The points will be denser in the inner ring if you generate the distance uniformly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get uniform distribution of random point in the ring, one should take relative areas of thin circular regions into account. [How it works for the circle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html)
[image]

For your case generate uniform distribution of SquaredR in range of squared inner and outer radii. Pseudocode:

```
 Fi  = RandomUniform(0, 2 * Pi)
 SquaredR  = RandomUniform(inner*inner, outer*outer)
 R = Sqrt(SquaredR)
 x,y = R * Cos(Fi), R * Sin(Fi)
```

Answer (score 6):

Take a random angle and a random distance between the two constraints; you'll need to produce a [uniform distribution in a circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445536/continuous-uniform-distribution-over-a-circle-with-radius-r):

```
from math import sin, cos, radians, pi, sqrt

def meteorites():
    angle = uniform(0, 2 * pi)  # in radians
    distance = sqrt(uniform(4, 12.25))
    return distance * cos(angle), distance * sin(angle)
```

Comment: Perfect. Dank je wel!

Comment: Yeah, I realised when I saw the timings. I didn't see your comment as I was busy researching proper distribution across a circle ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You're getting random points that don't fall on your ring because these two lines don't do what you want:

```
x[i] = meteorites()[0]
y[i] = meteorites()[1]
```

These assign an `x` value from one point on the ring to `x[i]`, and the `y` value *from a different point on the ring* to `y[i]`. You get coordinates from different points because you're calling `meteorites()` twice.

Instead, you probably want to call the function once, and then assign to each coordinate, or do an assignment with iterable-unpacking where both targets are on the left side of the equals sign:

```
x[i], y[i] = meteorites()
```

Answer (score 3):

Your implementation will also work if you correct one line: insstead of calling `meteorites()` twice, call just once.

```
x = np.zeros(1000)
y = np.zeros(1000)
for i in range(1000):
    x[i], y[i] = meteorites()
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

as @Martijn Pieters suggested, simply draw the polar coordinates uniformly in the range you require.

```
theta = uniform(0,2*np.pi)
r = uniform(2.,3.5)
x = r*np.cos(theta)
y = r*np.sin(theta)
```

**EDIT:** There will be equal probability for every point in the ring to occur.

But practically there will be less pixels for a given `theta` the closer `r` is to the lower limit. So "meteorites" with smaller `r` will occur with larger probability.

I believe this effect is negligeble.

**EDIT 2:** MBo's answer is better. Code:

```
theta = uniform(0, 2 * np.pi)
r = np.sqrt(uniform(2.0 ** 2, 3.5 ** 2)) # draw from sqrt distribution
x = r * np.cos(theta)
y = r * np.sin(theta)
```

Comment: A circle has 2pi radians; you are laying out a location on *half* the ring.

Answer (score 2):

I would also rather run through a loop that picks a random angle and a random distance within your ring range. Then calculate the coords from that.

But in your code the first problem is see is that should write:

```
x[i],y[i] = meteorites()
```

instead of

```
x[i] = meteorites()[0] 
y[i] = meteorites()[1]
```

In your example, you're called meteorites() twice resulting in the x and y two different meteorites.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following to generate 1000 samples using numpy:

```
import numpy 
n = 1000
phi = numpy.random.uniform(0, 2*numpy.pi, n)
r = numpy.random.uniform(2, 3.5, n)
```

Then x, y coordinates can be constructed as follows using the transformation from radial to cartesian coordinates:

```
x = r * numpy.cos(phi)
y = r * numpy.sin(phi)
```

This shows the power of numpy, as x and y are now arrays without needing to iterate over n.