# Sample uniformly in a multidimensional ring without rejection

Tags: python, matlab, random, geometry, uniform-distribution

The algorithm in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5408276/3791466) tells us how to efficiently sample from a multidimensional ball. Is there a way to similarly efficiently sample from a multidimensional ring , i.e. have `r1<r<r2`

I hope that a not too complex modification of that scaling function 
`r*(gammainc(s2/2,n/2).^(1/n))./sqrt(s2)` is possible. (Mediocrity disclaimer: haven't even figured the algebra/geometry for the original scaling function yet).

Original matlab code copypasted:

```
function X = randsphere(m,n,r)

% This function returns an m by n array, X, in which 
% each of the m rows has the n Cartesian coordinates 
% of a random point uniformly-distributed over the 
% interior of an n-dimensional hypersphere with 
% radius r and center at the origin.  The function 
% 'randn' is initially used to generate m sets of n 
% random variables with independent multivariate 
% normal distribution, with mean 0 and variance 1.
% Then the incomplete gamma function, 'gammainc', 
% is used to map these points radially to fit in the 
% hypersphere of finite radius r with a uniform % spatial distribution.
% Roger Stafford - 12/23/05

X = randn(m,n);
s2 = sum(X.^2,2);
X = X.*repmat(r*(gammainc(s2/2,n/2).^(1/n))./sqrt(s2),1,n);
```

Equivalent python code with demo from [Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44782884/3791466):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import gammainc
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
def sample(center,radius,n_per_sphere):
    r = radius
    ndim = center.size
    x = np.random.normal(size=(n_per_sphere, ndim))
    ssq = np.sum(x**2,axis=1)
    fr = r*gammainc(ndim/2,ssq/2)**(1/ndim)/np.sqrt(ssq)
    frtiled = np.tile(fr.reshape(n_per_sphere,1),(1,ndim))
    p = center + np.multiply(x,frtiled)
    return p

fig1 = plt.figure(1)
ax1 = fig1.gca()
center = np.array([0,0])
radius = 1
p = sample(center,radius,10000)
ax1.scatter(p[:,0],p[:,1],s=0.5)
ax1.add_artist(plt.Circle(center,radius,fill=False,color='0.5'))
ax1.set_xlim(-1.5,1.5)
ax1.set_ylim(-1.5,1.5)
ax1.set_aspect('equal')
```

Comment: How many dimensions ?

Comment: @Yves Arbitrary number. In practice this will be used first in toy problems in 2D, then on intermediate in 6D and then in problems with dimensionality of order of hundreds.

Comment: @MBo Done. There were some markdown rendering problems.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes. Besides, even in low-D rejection becomes slow for narrow rings.

Answer (score 5):

The last method [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html)<sup>(1)</sup>  is suitable for any dimensional sphere:

To pick a random point on a sphere:
- generate N Gaussian random variables `x1,x2..xN`
- get norm of x[i]

```
 L = Sqrt(x1*x1 + x2*x2 + .. + xn*xn)
 ux1 = x1 / L
 ux2 = x2 / L
 ...
```

Then the distribution of the vectors ux[i] is uniform over the surface S<sup>N-1</sup>

To provide uniform distribution in the ring:
- generate uniform random in range

`R_NPow  = RandomUniform(R_Inner`<sup>N</sup>`, R_Outer`<sup>N</sup>)

and get radius  (like [this 2D case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41912170/trying-to-generate-random-x-y-coordinates-within-a-ring-in-python/41912356#41912356))

`R = R_NPow`<sup>1/N</sup>

then calculate resulting point coordinates:

```
res_x1 = R * ux1
res_x2 = R * ux2
...
res_xn = R * uxn
```

(1) Muller, M. E. "A Note on a Method for Generating Points Uniformly on -Dimensional Spheres." Comm. Assoc. Comput. Mach. 2, 19-20, Apr. 1959.

Answer (score 2):

I actually ended up using the inverse cdf method applied to points uniformly distributed on a sphere

like so

```
def random_uniform_ring(center=np.array([0,0]),R=1,r=0,nsamples=1):
    """
    generate point uniformly distributed in a ring
    """
    nd = len(center)
    x = np.random.normal(size = (nsamples,nd))
    x = x / np.linalg.norm(x,axis=-1,keepdims=True) #generate on unit sphere
    # using the inverse cdf method
    u = np.random.uniform(size=(nsamples))
    sc = (u*(R**nd-r**nd)+r**nd)**(1/nd) #this is inverse the cdf of ring volume as a function of radius
    return x*sc[:,None]+center
```

To test

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import gammainc
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
def test1():
    fig1 = plt.figure(1)
    ax1 = fig1.gca()
    # center = np.zeros((600))
    # center = np.array([0,0])
    center = np.array([2,1])
    r = 0.5
    R = 1.
    n = 1000
    p = random_uniform_ring(center,R,r,n)
    assert p.shape[0]==n
    ax1.scatter(p[:,0],p[:,1],s=0.5)
    ax1.add_artist(plt.Circle(center,R,fill=False,color='0.5'))
    ax1.add_artist(plt.Circle(center,r,fill=False,color='0.5'))
    ax1.set_xlim(-R-0.5+center[0],R+0.5+center[0])
    ax1.set_ylim(-R-0.5+center[1],R+0.5+center[1])
    ax1.set_aspect('equal')
    plt.show()


test1()
```

[image: sampling_uniformly_in_a_ring]

This might be equivalent to @Mbo's answer, but unfortunately I don't really  have time to test. If somebody could test his answer, I would gladly accept.

Comment: Emm... Seems my yesterday's comment has disappeared. (I approved that method is exactly the same as mine)

Comment: > disappeared:
wasn't me :)

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error, I was able to get it done with the gammainc approach. The math behind it is beyond my depth, but I basically tweeked the coefficient 2 in gammainc to a power z to improve uniformity.

Also tested it in 3D and it seems to work fine.

(this had been in my todo list for a while, thanks for the ideas!)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import gammainc
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def sample_ring(center,r1,r2,n_points):
    nd = center.size
    x = np.random.normal(size=(n_points, nd))
    sq = np.sum(x**2,axis=1)
    z = (r2-r1)/r2
    fr = (r2-r1)*gammainc(nd/2**z,sq/2**z)**(1/nd)/np.sqrt(sq) + r1/np.sqrt(sq)
    frtiled = np.tile(fr.reshape(n_points,1),(1,nd))
    p = center + np.multiply(x,frtiled)
    return p

fig1 = plt.figure(1)
ax1 = fig1.gca()
center = np.array([0,0])
r1 = 1.5
R2 = 3
p = sample_ring(center,r1,R2,5000)
ax1.scatter(p[:,0],p[:,1],s=0.5)
ax1.add_artist(plt.Circle(center,r1,fill=False,color='0.5'))
ax1.add_artist(plt.Circle(center,R2,fill=False,color='0.5'))
ax1.set_xlim(-4,4)
ax1.set_ylim(-4,4)
ax1.set_aspect('equal')

fig3 = plt.figure(3)
ax3 = plt.gca(projection='3d')
ax3.set_aspect("equal")
theta, phi = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:10j, 0:np.pi:10j]
c_3d = np.array([0,0,0])
r1_3d = 0.5
x1 = c_3d[0] + r1_3d*np.cos(theta)*np.sin(phi)
y1 = c_3d[1] + r1_3d*np.sin(theta)*np.sin(phi)
z1 = c_3d[2] + r1_3d*np.cos(phi)
r2_3d = 1.4
x2 = c_3d[0] + r2_3d*np.cos(theta)*np.sin(phi)
y2 = c_3d[1] + r2_3d*np.sin(theta)*np.sin(phi)
z2 = c_3d[2] + r2_3d*np.cos(phi)
ax3.plot_wireframe(x1, y1, z1, color="r")
ax3.plot_wireframe(x2, y2, z2, color="r")
p = sample_ring(c_3d,r1_3d,r2_3d,1000)
ax3.scatter(p[:,0],p[:,1],p[:,2], c='b', marker='o')
ax3.set_xlim(-1.5, 1.5)
ax3.set_ylim(-1.5, 1.5)
ax3.set_zlim(-1.5, 1.5)
```

[image: uniform sample in ring]

[image: uniform sample 3d ring]

Comment: Looks legit :) Hopefully I'll find some time to test or prove correctness in the next two days.

Comment: As much as I would like this to work, it seems non-uniform. Here is the 50000 sample image with your code https://imgoat.com/uploads/f39f8317fb/60646.png

Comment: Indeed. I'll bring the gamma-incomplete method to the board with some friends to see if we can crack the math. For now, your inverse cdf code worked with everything I threw at it. I'd say that should be an accepted answer.