# Random function in python to generate random pair inside a circle

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, random, geometry, coordinates

In python how to generate a random pair of points (x,y) that lies inside a circle of radius r.

Basically the x and y should satisfy the condition x^2 + y^2 = r^2.

Comment: Question is vague - `inside a circle of radius r` assumes x^2 + y^2 **<=** r^2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generate uniformly distributed point inside origin-centered circle of radius r, you can generate two uniform values `t,u` in range `0..1` and use [the next formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html):

```
import math, random
r = 4
t = random.random()
u = random.random()
x = r * math.sqrt(t) * math.cos(2 * math.pi * u)
y = r * math.sqrt(t) * math.sin(2 * math.pi * u)
print (x,y)
```

Comment: What changes can be made such that x and y lie between the region of two concentric circles of radius r1 and r2.  r1^2 <= x^2 + y^2 <= r2^2

Comment: @MBo I think `t` should be in range `Uniform[r1**2/r2**2, 1]`

Comment: For ring -  generate value t in range (r1/r2)**2..1 with RandomUniform and use x = r2 * math.sqrt(t)... [Corresponding answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41912170/trying-to-generate-random-x-y-coordinates-within-a-ring-in-python/41912356#41912356)

Answer (score 2):

Using numpy to generate more than one point at a time:

```py
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

n_samples = 1000

r = 4
# make a simple unit circle 
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n_samples)
a, b = r * np.cos(theta), r * np.sin(theta)

t = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=n_samples)
u = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=n_samples)

x = r*np.sqrt(t) * np.cos(2*np.pi*u)
y = r*np.sqrt(t) * np.sin(2*np.pi*u)

# Plotting
plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
plt.plot(a, b, linestyle='-', linewidth=2, label='Circle', color='red')
plt.scatter(x, y, marker='o',  label='Samples')
plt.ylim([-r*1.5,r*1.5])
plt.xlim([-r*1.5,r*1.5])
plt.grid()
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show(block=True)
```

which results in:

[image]